# Ruby on Rails ERB Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question with turning this html into erb.

```
<button name="support" type="button" value="Get Support" class="brightOrange">
<span>Get Support</span>
</button>
```

I've been trying to do something like this in rails.

```
<% form_tag get_support_path do %> 
    <%= text_field_tag :email, "Email:" %>
    <% submit_tag "Join", :class=>"brightOrange" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help in advance. Not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to do:

```
<%= button_to "Get support", "#", :class => 'brightOrange' %>
```

Other than that, you are missing an '=' in

```
<%= submit_tag "Join", :class=>"brightOrange" %>
```